# ComoContar Elementos Repetidos em uma Imagem com Phyton

Tags: python

Salve turma, gostaria de saber se é possível contar a quantidade e elementos repetidos em uma imagem.

Exemplo: Em uma imagem tem 10 cadeados fechados e 5 cadeados abertos. o script precisa retornar a quantidade de cadeados aberto nessa imagem.

Eu tentei usar o pyautogui para comparar a uma imagem que recortei do cadeado, com as demais na imagem original, consigo localizar apenas um cadeado, porem os demais não localiza.

Segue o código:

```
import pyautogui
from pyscreeze import locateCenterOnScreen

cont = 0

while True:
    cadeado = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('cadeado_aberto.png')

    if cadeado is None:
        print('Nenhum cadeado aberto localizado')
    else:
        pyautogui.moveTo(cadeado)
        cont += cont
        print(cont)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está somando seu contador com ele mesmo, ou seja, `cont += cont` é a mesma coisa que **0 + 0**.

O correto é `cont +=1`

Ele te retorna 1, pois na primeira iteração ele acaba conseguindo fazer e depois não tem mais contagem.

Comment: Fiz a correção aqui mano, porem continua reconhecendo apenas a primeira imagem que ele localiza, e fica incrementando a cada loop. Sabe como posso fazer para ele localizar o proximo cadeado? Tem alguma maneira de fazer uma verificação caso o scrypt ja tenha visitado aquela imagem, ele procurar a proxima?

Comment: Eu nunca utilizei o locate para multiplos resultados, mas seguindo uma lógica básica eu imagino que você deva fazer um laço que percorra a imagem, pulando a cada X pixels (o X seria exatamente o tamanho do cadeado). Assim ele faria a verificação em um pedaço, adiciona o cadeado no contador se tiver e continua de onde parou. Espero que ajude.